# analog setinterval in java

Tags: java

I need to check the url (once per second)

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.print(engine.getLocation());
        }
    };
timer.schedule( task, 1000 );
```

but I don't need schedule

In JavaScript it would look like

```
var interval = self.setInterval(function(){
    console.log(mywindow.location.href);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
timer.schedule( task, 0L ,1000L);
```

will check every second.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourTimerTask, new Date(), 1000l);
```

... which will schedule execution starting now, each second.

Note that the start time and rate are not guaranteed to execute precisely time-wise.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) for API documentation on the method.